# Blackberry Location Service fails on real device?

Tags: blackberry, gps, location

I've been trying to get longitude and latitude values using Blackberry's GPS listener. My device is a blackberry torch. The simulator I use also is a blackberry torch. The GPS listener seems to be working on the sim, but once on a real device it fails. When I say fail, it does not pick up longitude and latitude values, rather, it struggles to even connect to the GPS. I checked my options menu, and I'm able to pick up long and lat values from the location settings, so why would my app not be able to do it? 
I call the class handleGPS in another class, i.e by doing this:

```
new handleGPS();
```

As I said, using the SIM I the provider finds my location after about 10 seconds. On the real device, I debug it and it does reach this statement (as the System.out's are printed)

```
try {
    lp = LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);
    System.out.println("location Provider");
    lp.setLocationListener(new handleGPSListener(), 10, -1, -1);
    //lp.setLocationListener(listener, interval, timeout, maxAge)
    System.out.println("location Provider after listener");
} catch (LocationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However no values get returned. Below is my code.

GPS class:

```
public class handleGPS extends TimerTask {
 //Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
private Timer timer;
LocationProvider lp = null;
public handleGPS()
{
    timer =new Timer();
    System.out.println("timer");
    GPS();

    //timer.schedule(this, 0, 10000);
    timer.schedule(this, 1000);
}

public void GPS() {
    Criteria cr = new Criteria();
    cr.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    cr.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    cr.setCostAllowed(false);
    cr.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    //cr.setPreferredResponseTime(1000);

    System.out.println("GPS ()");
    try {
        lp = LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);
        System.out.println("location Provider");
        lp.setLocationListener(new handleGPSListener(), 10, -1, -1);
        //lp.setLocationListener(listener, interval, timeout, maxAge)
        System.out.println("location Provider after listener");
    } catch (LocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// });

public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lp.setLocationListener(new handleGPSListener(), 10, -1, -1);
}
```

}

And here is the handler:

```
public class handleGPSListener implements LocationListener {
Coordinates c = null;
private static double lat=0.00;
private static double lon=0.00;



Database sqliteDB;
String username;
public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public String URL = "http://77.245.77.195:60010/Webservice/IDLMobile.asmx?WSDL";
public static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Get_OfferCount_By_Location";
public static final String METHOD_NAME = "Get_OfferCount_By_Location";
private double x,y;
public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider loc, Location location) {  //method to update as the location changes.
    System.out.println("class handle GPS Listener");
    if (loc == null) {  //condition to check if the location information is null.
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("GPS not supported!"); //dialog box to alert gps is not started.
                System.out.println("Problem 1");
                return;
            }
        });
    } else {    //if not checked.
        System.out.println("OK");
        switch (loc.getState()) {   //condition to check state of the location.
        case (LocationProvider.AVAILABLE):  //condition to check if the location is available.

            System.out.println("Provider is AVAILABLE");

            try {
                location = loc.getLocation(-1); //location to get according to user present.
            } catch (LocationException e) {
                return;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (location != null && location.isValid()) {   //condition to check if the location is not null and is valid.
                c = location.getQualifiedCoordinates(); //to get the coordinates of the location.
            }
            if (c != null) {    //condition to check if the location is not null.
                lat = c.getLatitude();  //retrieve the latitude values into variable.
                lon = c.getLongitude(); //retrieve the longitude values into variable.

                System.out.println("lat and lon"+lat+lon);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(
                        new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                updateFields();
                                getValues();
                                // Dialog.alert(lat+"GPS supported!"+lon);
                                return;
                            }

                            private void getValues() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try {
                                    URI uri = URI
                                            .create("file:///SDCard/"
                                                    + "database3.db");  //database3 to retrieve the values from location table.
                                    sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
                                    Statement st = null;
                                    st = sqliteDB
                                            .createStatement("SELECT Latitude,Longitude FROM Location");//statement to retrieve the lat and lon values.
                                    st.prepare();
                                    Cursor c = st.getCursor();//cursor to point.
                                    Row r;
                                    int i = 0;
                                    while (c.next()) {  //loop to execute until there are no values in the cursor.
                                        r = c.getRow(); //store the values in row.
                                        i++;
                                        lat=Double.parseDouble(r.getString(0)); //retrieve the latitude values from the database and store in variable.
                                        lon=Double.parseDouble(r.getString(1)); //retrieve the longitude values from the database and store in variable.
                                        System.out.println(r.getString(0)
                                                + " Latitude");
                                        System.out.println(r.getString(1)
                                                + " Longitude");

                                    }

                                    st.close();
                                    sqliteDB.close();
                                }

                                catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println(e.getMessage()
                                            + " wut");
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {
                                    URI uri = URI
                                            .create("file:///SDCard/"
                                                    + "database1.db");
                                    sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
                                    Statement st = null;
                                    st = sqliteDB
                                            .createStatement("SELECT Name FROM People");
                                    st.prepare();
                                    Cursor c = st.getCursor();
                                    Row r;
                                    int i = 0;
                                    while (c.next()) {
                                        r = c.getRow();
                                        i++;
                                        username=r.getString(0);

                                        System.out.println(r.getString(0)
                                                + "Name");


                                    }

                                    st.close();
                                    sqliteDB.close();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                SoapObject rpc = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                                rpc.addProperty("Username", username);
                                rpc.addProperty("latitude", String.valueOf(lat));
                                rpc.addProperty("longitude", String.valueOf(lon));
                                rpc.addProperty("distance", "1.5");
                                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                                envelope.bodyOut = rpc;
                                envelope.dotNet = true;
                                envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;

                                HttpTransport ht = new HttpTransport(URL);
                                ht.debug = true;

                                try {
                                    ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                                    System.out.println("IN TRY");
                                    SoapObject resultProperties = (SoapObject) envelope
                                            .getResponse();

                                    System.out.println("username INT RIGHT HERE " + resultProperties.getProperty(0));
                                    System.out.println("username INT RIGHT HERE " + resultProperties.getProperty(1).toString());
                                    System.out.println("username INT RIGHT HERE " + resultProperties.getProperty(2).toString());
                                    System.out.println("lat and lon PARSE HERE " + lat+"\n"+lon);

                                    /* here is the notification code */

                                    //ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();    
                                    //EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("logosmall.png");
                                    //ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon( image );

                                    //ApplicationIndicator indicator = reg.register( icon, false, true);
                                    //indicator.setIcon(icon);
                                    //indicator.setVisible(true);

                                    //setupIndicator();
                                    //setVisible(true, 0);

                                    //NotificationsManager.triggerImmediateEvent(1, 0, 20, null);
                                    //NotificationsManager.




                                    /* end notification code */


                                } catch (org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException ex2) {

                                } catch (Exception ex) {

                                    String bah = ex.toString();

                                }
                            }

                            private void updateFields() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try {

                                    URI myURI = URI
                                            .create("file:///SDCard/"
                                                    + "database3.db");
                                    sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);
                                    Statement st = null;
                                    Statement oops = null;
                                    st = sqliteDB
                                    .createStatement("SELECT Latitude,Longitude FROM Location");
                            st.prepare();
                            Cursor c = st.getCursor();
                            Row r;
                            int i = 0;
                            while (c.next()) {
                                r = c.getRow();
                                i++;
                                x=Double.parseDouble(r.getString(0));
                                y=Double.parseDouble(r.getString(1));
                                System.out.println(r.getString(0)
                                        + " Latitude in update fields");
                                System.out.println(r.getString(1)
                                        + " Longitude in update fields");

                            }
                                    st = sqliteDB
                                            .createStatement("UPDATE Location SET Latitude='"
                                                    + lat
                                                    + "' "
                                                    + "WHERE Latitude="
                                                    + "'" + x + "'" + "");
                                    oops = sqliteDB
                                            .createStatement("UPDATE Location SET Longitude='"
                                                    + lon
                                                    + "' "
                                                    + "WHERE Longitude="
                                                    + "'" + y + "'" + "");
                                    System.out.println("location updated");
                                    System.out
                                            .println("lat and lon values are"
                                                    + lat + lon);
                                    st.prepare();
                                    oops.prepare();
                                    st.execute();
                                    oops.execute();
                                    st.close();
                                    oops.close();
                                    sqliteDB.close();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });
            }

        }
    }
}

public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) {
    if (newState == LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE) {
        // GPS unavailable due to IT policy specification
        System.out.println("GPS unavailable due to IT policy specification");
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("GPS unavailable due to IT policy specification");

                return;
            }
        });
    } else if (newState == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE) {
        // no GPS fix
        System.out.println("GPS temporarily unavailable due to IT policy specification");
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("no GPS fix");
                return;
            }
        });
    }

}


public ApplicationIndicator _indicator; 
public static handleGPSListener _instance;

public void setupIndicator() {

    //Setup notification 
    if (_indicator == null) {
        ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
        _indicator = reg.getApplicationIndicator();

        if(_indicator == null) {
            ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon(EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource ("daslogo.png"));
            _indicator = reg.register(icon, false, true);  
            _indicator.setValue(0);
            _indicator.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

}

public void setVisible(boolean visible, int count) {

    if (_indicator != null) {
        if (visible) {
            _indicator.setVisible(true);
            _indicator.setValue(count);
        } else {
            _indicator.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

}

handleGPSListener () {

}

public static handleGPSListener getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = new handleGPSListener ();
    }
    return(_instance);
}
public double returnLong(){
    return lon;
}
public double returnLat(){
    return lat;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler's locationUpdated method is never being called, right? If you call getLocation directly does it work?

I was unable to get the listener to work correctly and eventually moved to using a timer instead from which I call getLocation...

I suspect that the listener only *listens* to events and does not create them, i.e. if something asked for the location, the listener will receive it as well, but if nothing asked for the location you get nothing.

In GPS it is wise to never trust the simulator, it lies.   :)

Comment: it certainly is being called. I think this will solve my issue <3